# LLenar Select con HTML y PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select

estoy realizando un pagina web en la cual el usuario va a llenar un select y se desplegara información, pero creo tengo un problema con la base, no me muestra los datos. Podrían ayudarme por favor, adjunto códigos

CODIGO PHP

```
<select name="" id="">
    <?php 
    require("conectar.php");
    $enlace = $enlace();
    $sql = "SELECT nocuenta, nombre_alumno FROM alumno";
    $stmt = $enlace -> prepare($sql);
    $result = $stmt -> execute();
    $row = $stmt -> fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    foreach($rows as $row){
```

Comment: Buenas, Lizeth, bienvenido/a al sitio. ¿Puedes indicar más detalles? ¿Qué significa "tengo un problema con la base"? ¿Te está apareciendo algún error al intentar ejecutar la consulta? Intenta capturar dicho error y añade esa información a la pregunta, por favor. Así como la parte en donde defines $enlace().

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué significa está línea en tu código `$enlace = $enlace();`?

Comment: @A.Cedano se no ta que el `enlace()` es una llamada que retorna un objeto mysqli() con el acceso a la base de datos

Comment: @John, de ser así, debería quitar la `$` para llamar a dicha función: **`enlace();`**

Comment: Después de arreglar la conexión corrige el fetch, lo tienes que hacer sobre el resultado y no sobre la sentencia.

Comment: @A.Cedano  se pueden usar así, solo cuanto el valor de la variable se llama igual a una función

Comment: ¿En serio @John? Primera vez que leo eso. ¿Me puedes pasar referencia? Aunque sea permitido, no crea que sea una forma convencional de escribir código en PHP. Lizeth, intenta poner `var_dump($rows);` **justo debajo** de esta línea: `$row = $stmt -> fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);`, y, muestra la parte del `foreach`, no vemos si estás usando la sintaxis adecuado para `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` por ejemplo.

Comment: @A.Cedano este es el funcionamiento https://paiza.io/projects/e/TMR3xJnLxFPVmpTwx44AIA  si bien no es la forma mas ortodoxa funciona, no recuerdo en que parte del manual esta pero si recuerdo que lo vi en algún momento

Comment: @John, PHP tiene algo llamado [Funciones variables](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.variable-functions.php), para un uso muy específico. En tu ejemplo no tiene sentido complicarse tanto cuando puedes hacer un `echo prueba();` para el mismo resultado, ahorrándote estas dos declaraciones: `$a="prueba";` y `$d=$a();` y la confusión que de ello deriva... Si en el código de OP la conexión es devuelta desde una función llamada `enlace`, entonces basta con hacer algo así: `$enlace=enlace();`No creo que para este caso se justifique el uso de *funciones variables*.

Comment: @A.Cedano el codigo que puse es un ejemplo ultra basico, que se puede usar en otros ambitos, yo lo describi para un uso, esto puede aplicarse a clases y a llamadas de metodos que sean variantes como lo dice el manual.

Answer (score 0):

Para que corresponda con el lazo foreach, la instrucción

```
$row = $stmt -> fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

debe ser:

```
$rows = $stmt -> fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```